# Accessing data from a running ActiveX control in another application

Tags: c#, c++, activex

I have one application that contains a spreadsheet ActiveX control. Inspect.exe tells me it is a "SPR32x30_SpreadSheet", which I believe comes from a file SPR32x30.ocx packaged with this application.

I want to be able to extract the data from the cells in that spreadsheet into my own application (preferably C++ or C#).

I was hoping I'd be able to do something like find the memory being used by this control in the 3rd party application, then read that into one of the structs in SPR32x30.ocx in my own application.

Is this even possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Before you get bombed with COM answers, you better clarify whether or not you have access via COM interface to the process hosting the OCX as an out-of-proc server (with your app as the client), or whether you're just trying to slurp data from a process you have zero control over. If the process is just a client itself and exposes no means to query their control, you're not going to find this an easy task. (easy being a relative term).

Comment: As far as I am aware, it's just a client that doesn't expose a means of querying. How would I confirm this?

Comment: If it has no automation documentation, chances are you already have confirmed it, which is quite the bummer, because it would have been considerably easier on your part. I suspect you're quite-correctl its just a client.